# how change the value when show on the table laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, crud

i try to change jenis_id (int) to string when they are show up in the table blade.
[the value in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihNym.png)
and here is my try

```
@if($ad->jenis_id = '1')
    <td>Terkait</td>
@elseif ($ad->jenis_id = '2')
    <td>Informasi</td>
@endif
```

[but only "terkait" show in column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPzCW.png)

Comment: vote to close as typo

Comment: Yoda condition helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator isn't `=` to compare... Use `==` like:

```php
@if($ad->jenis_id == 1)
    <td>Terkait</td>
@elseif ($ad->jenis_id == 2)
    <td>Informasi</td>
@endif
```

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is a single `=` char. You just assign a value to a property instead comparing. You should consider using `==` or `===`. First one checks only value, so coercing takes a place. Triple equality char checks both value AND type.